# Random net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, jsonp

Read before posting as duplicate.

I'm currently making a website that simulates the stock market. Every second, it makes an ajax request to `http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp` to update stock prices. I use http GET and a jsonp request, through jquery (standard random callback). Most of the time, it works. Sometimes, however, it stops working and I get error 101 `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`, and, after a while, starts working again. This is different from some other issues, because it works most of the time. I am using google chrome on this, though.

Answer (score 0):

the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET is generally a return message from the webserver. It is  reset your TCP/IP connection. What webserver are you using?

Comment: I don't own the webserver. It's a third party stock website at `dev.markitondemand.com`.

Comment: Contact your host, there's something up with your hosting.